# CSS not linking to HTML filezilla connection perhaps

Tags: css

I cannot connect my app.css file into my html and I need your help please!
I am starting to build my first website and made a CSS file called app.css which is saved in the same local folder as the html file.

I wrote this in the header of the html to link it but whenever I upload it to filezilla and refresh my browser, I do not see any of the changes.

```
      <link href="app.css" rel=stylesheet>
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Check your browser’s network tab. Is the CSS file being loaded? Have you tried loading the path of the CSS file in your browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that css file and html file exists in same location. You must put link tag in your head tag, like the following example:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
</head>
```